# Access database in real time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this situation: we have a database with products (price, stock, name ....). 
One of our clients wants to sell  our products on his website and want to access our stock in real time.
How can I do this? I don't want to give him database credentials.

Comment: You need a kind of web service to do that. Oh, and this has nothing to do with real-time whatsoever.

Comment: Is it possible to return a class and  List<T> from  webservice function?

Comment: Depends on how you implement it. For a pure C# web service, this is certainly possible, however it merely forces your client to also use C# and therefore is mainly a good option if you're writing both server and client yourself. It is probably better to return some XML or JSON, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Make an API**

What I mean is, create a system that allows the customer to form queries and get results programmatically through a given entry point.

An example would be a web address like `http://api.otix.com/products/iphone5s` which runs a query on the database and produces the results of the information in a format convenient for the client (html page, JSON, XML ... whatever).

That way the customer just goes to `http://api.otix.com/products/product-name-here` and they get an up-to-date data on the status of the product.